# React LinkedStateMixin with geocomplete

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails, geocomplete

Currently using Rails 4 with [react-rails gem](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) and [geocomplete](https://github.com/ubilabs/geocomplete) gem.

All worked fine(ish) until I've changed the front end to use Reactjs. When I type few characters, the autocomplete list shows up. I choose the location but only the few characters are shown in my State. Example: When I type "bir", the list for "Birmingham" shows. If I select "Birmingham, United Kingdom", only "bir" gets stored, why?

**js.jsx:**

```
var NewProject = React.createClass({
  mixins: [React.addons.LinkedStateMixin],

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      location: this.props.data.location
    }
  },

  render: function(){
    $("#location").geocomplete({ details: "form" });
    return <input type="text" id="location" valueLink={this.linkState('location')} />;
  }
});
```

How to get the full value of the string when selected no matter if I typed in few characters?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is geocomplete does some magic to the input which doesn't play well with how React observes the modification of the field. I would try to use other solution for autocompletion but if you need to stick with geocomplete you could try to use jquery + the plain onChange method to detect changes in the field. Something like this:

```js
var NewProject = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      location: this.props.data.location
    }
  },
  
  onGeoChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({
      location:  $("#location").val()
    });
  },

  render: function(){
    $("#location").geocomplete({ details: "form" });
    return <input type="text" id="location" onChange={this.onGeoChange} />;
  }
});
```

Comment: Seems not to work. Basically i need to scrap geocomplete?

Comment: That would be the easiest solution. You could use GeoSuggest (also from ubilabs) which is designed specifically for React: https://github.com/ubilabs/react-geosuggest